# How to play animation just once whenever i shoot a bullet ( flash animation)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation, playback

(check image) Hi! I actually have two questions,

**THE FIRST ONE:** I have two flash animations that I want to play in front of the tank's turret whenever I shoot a bullet (I have different weapons with different fire delays, machine gun, bombs..) so how can I play that flash animation to work in with the fire delay of a gun ? (note that if I uncheck loop time, the animation stops in the last sprite + I don't know how to replay it).

**SECOND QUESTION:** I want simply to animate my turret when I shoot I just want it to go back a little and return, you know what I mean, only in unity, how, please?
give me just the idea of working and I'll do my research :) thank you!

I have tried to enable my animation when I shoot and uncheck the loop time, but the animation stops at the last animation sprite and I don't know how to replay it.

[image: The image]

Answer (score 2):

Using Unity's built in animator, I'm assuming you are using this, you need to have at least have 2 states, in your case Idle and Fire. You would then set the transitions of the animations to go from one another, Fire -> Idle and Idle -> Fire.

Within the Idle-> Fire you will need add a trigger due to it only happening once.
You may also need 2 SpriteRenderer Components to allow for the display of the Shot effect, just make a child GameObject with it and edit it in the Animation Window.
Triggers reset as soon as the transition has been made.

If you do not have a trigger go to the parameter tab and click the '+' button which will allow you to create a new trigger. Now that that is created, in your code whenever you want your tank / boat to fire just add. *referenceToAnimator*.SetTrigger ("*triggerName*");

Bringing up your delay you could always add an additional wait state that mirrors the idle state but only runs for the selected amount of time. Your new Animator would look like.

Idle -> Trigger -> Wait -> Fire -> Idle

Comment: thanks for answering ! will it work if i use only one sprite ? and make it go back and forth with the animator ?

Comment: Yes, it you have your turret's SpriteRenderer on a child object you can modify the transform's position within the animation to allow for the turrets movement.